# How can I access the collection item being validated when using RuleForEach?

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation to validate an object, and because this object has a collection member I'm trying to use `RuleForEach`. For example, suppose we have `Customer` and `Orders`, and we want to ensure that no customer order has a total value that exceeds the maximum allowed for that customer:

```
this.RuleForEach(customer => customer.Orders)
    .Must((customer, orders) => orders.Max(order => order.TotalValue) <= customer.MaxOrderValue)
```

So far, so good. However, I also need to record additional information about the context of the error (e.g. where in a data file the error was found). I've found this quite difficult to achieve with FluentValidation, and my best solution so far is to use the `WithState` method. For example, if I find that the customer's address details are incorrect, I might do something like this:

```
this.RuleFor(customer => customer.Address)
    .Must(...)
    .WithState(customer => GetErrorContext(customer.Address))
```

(where `GetErrorContext` is a method of mine to extract the relevant details.

Now the problem I have is that when using `RuleForEach`, the method signature assumes that I'll provide an expression that references the *`Customer`*, not the particular `Order` that caused the validation failure. And I seem to have no way to tell which order had a problem. Hence, I can't store the appropriate context information.

In other words, I can only do this:

```
this.RuleForEach(customer => customer.Orders)
    .Must((customer, orders) => orders.Max(order => order.TotalValue) <= customer.MaxOrderValue)
    .WithState(customer => ...)
```

...when I really wanted to do this:

```
this.RuleForEach(customer => customer.Orders)
    .Must((customer, orders) => orders.Max(order => order.TotalValue) <= customer.MaxOrderValue)
    .WithState(order => ...)
```

Is there really no way to access the details (or even the index) of the collection item(s) that failed?

I suppose another way of looking at it is that I want `WithState` to have an equivalent `WithStateForEach`...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Currently there are no functionality in FluentValidation, that allows to set validation state the way you want. `RuleForEach` was designed to prevent creation of trivial validators for simple collection items, and it's implementation didn't cover all possible use cases.

You can create separate validator class for `Order` and apply it using `SetCollectionValidator` method. To access `Customer.MaxOrderValue` in `Must` method — add property to `Order`, that references backward to `Customer`:

```
public class CustomerValidator
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Orders).SetCollectionValidator(new OrderValidator());
    }
}

public class OrderValidator
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
         RuleFor(order => order.TotalValue)
             .Must((order, total) => total <= order.Customer.MaxOrderValue)
             .WithState(order => GetErrorInfo(order)); // pass order info into state
    }
}
```

If you still want to use `RuleForEach` method, you can use error message instead of custom state, because it have access to both parent and child item entity objects in one of overloads:

```
public class CustomerValidator
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(customer => customer.Orders)
            .Must((customer, order) => order.TotalValue) <= customer.MaxOrderValue)
            .WithMessage("order with Id = {0} have error. It's total value exceeds {1}, that is maximum for {2}",
                (customer, order) => order.Id,
                (customer, order) => customer.MaxOrderValue,
                (customer, order) => customer.Name);
    }
}
```

If you need to collect all indexes (or identifiers) of failed orders — you can do it with `Custom` rule, like here:

```
public CustomerValidator()
{
    Custom((customer, validationContext) =>
    {
        var isValid = true;
        var failedOrders = new List<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < customer.Orders.Count; i++)
        {
            if (customer.Orders[i].TotalValue > customer.MaxOrderValue)
            {
                isValid = false;
                failedOrders.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (!isValid){
            var errorMessage = string.Format("Error: {0} orders TotalValue exceed maximum TotalValue allowed", string.Join(",", failedOrders));
            return new ValidationFailure("", errorMessage) // return indexes of orders through error message
            {
                CustomState = GetOrdersErrorInfo(failedOrders) // set state object for parent model here
            };
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

**P.S.**

Do not forget that **your goal is to implement validation, not to use FluentValidation everywhere**. Sometimes we implement validation logic as a separate method, that works with `ViewModel` and fill `ModelState` in ASP.NET MVC.

If you can't find solution, that match your requirements, then manual implementation would be better than *crutchful* implementation with library.

Comment: Thanks. Both good ideas, although changing my model just to accommodate a limitation in FluentValidation doesn't sound good to me. The second idea isn't ideal for me, since I want an object (class) in my state, not just a string, but I'm sure it'd be sufficient for some. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any change to this, I have exactly the same problem, the rule is simple so I dont want to create a whole new validator for it and I want a class not just a message. 
Seems a bit poor to have the WithMessage taking both parent and child but not WithState.

Comment: @Kezza Added another solution, that could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

To complete @[David Levin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809446/12377747), FluentValidations teams added an other way in the release [8.5](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/releases/tag/8.5.0) :

[image: ChildRules]

You can find it [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html?highlight=ruleforeach#collections-of-complex-types).

With this, you will be able to use CustomState for each specific order.

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> 
{
      public CustomerValidator() 
      {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Orders).ChildRules(order => 
        {
          order.RuleFor(x => x.Total).GreaterThan(0)
                                     .WithMessage("The message you want to return")
                                     .WithState(x => new { Id = x.Id });
        });
      }
}
```