# RuleForEach - need access to item's index

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Considering this simplified code:

```
public class Request
{
    public List<Selection> Selections { get; set; }
}

public class Selection
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class RequestValidator(): AbstractValidator<Request>
{
    public RequestValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.Selections).SetValidator(new SelectionValidator());
    }
}

public class SelectionValidator : AbstractValidator<Selection>
{
    public SelectionValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotEqual(0); 
    }
}
```

If I have a `Selection` item with `Price` equal to 0 I do get error message:
`'Price' must not be equal to '0'.`

What I am missing is reference to which element in collection has this error.

When debugging i can clearly see that `Error.PropertyName` is set to  `Selections[0].Price`, but formatted name is missing that reference to the item.

Is there a way to correctly format the full property name? Maybe by using `.WithMessage()` but it does not seems to work.

[image: Example of debug info]

To make it clear, my goal is to have error on Nested Items look like this:
`<CollectionPropertyName>[<index>].<PropertyName> <error text>`. ex. `Selectons[0].Price must not be equal to 0`

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. Take a look at this thread, might be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213058/how-can-i-access-the-collection-item-being-validated-when-using-ruleforeach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `Validate` + `ValidateAsync` method to modify the result:

```
public abstract class ValidatorWithFullIndexerPath<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<T> context)
    {
        var result = base.Validate(context);
        FixIndexedPropertyErrorMessage(result);

        return result;
    }
    public override async Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<T> context, CancellationToken cancellation = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var result = await base.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation);
        FixIndexedPropertyErrorMessage(result);

        return result;
    }

    protected void FixIndexedPropertyErrorMessage(ValidationResult result)
    {
        if (result.Errors?.Any() ?? false)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                // check if 
                if (Regex.IsMatch(error.PropertyName, @"\[\d+\]") &&
                    error.FormattedMessagePlaceholderValues.TryGetValue("PropertyName", out var propertyName))
                {
                    // replace PropertyName with its full path
                    error.ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage
                        .Replace($"'{propertyName}'", $"'{error.PropertyName}'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, update `RequestValidator` and any other classes where full path is desired:

```
public class RequestValidator : ValidatorWithFullIndexerPath<Request>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already started working in the same direction - was hoping there is something build in available.

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidation 8.1 contains a new method `OverrideIndexer()` to support this:

- [release notes](https://jeremyskinner.co.uk/2018/12/06/fluentvalidation-81-released/)
- [github issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/874#issuecomment-417567970)
- [code](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/commit/65c10a3efbd6af5ca476d2753baad6e9394b0972)