# Fluent validation add rule with index

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I make a fluent validation class for this model

```
 public class OnlineCashierRequest
 {
    Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }      
    string ClientPhoneOrEmail { get; set; }    
    List<IOnlineCashierProduct> Products { get; set; }
 }

public interface IOnlineCashierProduct
{
     string Name { get; set; }
     decimal Amount { get; set; }
     int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I have a rule for `products` where Amount equals null. But how can I write in message row index like `$"Amount is less zero for row {rowIndex}"`

```
RuleForEach(t => t.Products)
    .Must(x => x.Amount < 0)
    .WithMessage(x => $"[{rowIndex}] Amount must be greater then zero\r\n");
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213058/how-can-i-access-the-collection-item-being-validated-when-using-ruleforeach

Comment: Why do you need the row index?

Comment: @chris For log validation exception

Comment: Would it not be better to use the `Name` of the `IOnlineCashierProduct` in the log message?

Comment: @chris No, there is also may be an error with empty productName

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html

```
RuleForEach(t => t.Products)
    .Must(x => x.Amount < 0)
    .WithMessage(x => $"[{CollectionIndex}] Amount must be greater than zero\r\n");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `$"[{{CollectionIndex}}] Amount must be greater than zero\r\n"` because of the string interpolation?